# Load some PHP link within a specific div in HTML page?

Tags: php, html, lampp

I made a side menu with these links:

```
<div id="menu_lat">
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/sgf/form_proposta.php">Orçamentos</a>
    <a href="relatorios.html">Relatórios</a>
    <a href="proximos.html">Próximos Eventos</a>
    <a href="chat.html">Chat</a>
</div>
```

When I open one of these, the content is opened in another div (which, in the first page, already has some content, which is an image):

```
<div id="conteudo">
    <img src="img/foto_inicial.jpg">
</div>
```

How could I load the PHP file inside this layer when I click that link?

Comment: You can do a 'frame' setup, but I don't recommend that. You can also assign a javascript function to run and change the html contents of the conteudo div to the html returned from that page. Don't have time to do the code for you atm, but those are my ideas.

Comment: You won't be able to include any PHP directive(s) in your `.html` files, unless you use `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` in your `.htaccess` file. You could use an iframe, but that could complicate things. It will be far more easier, if you changed your entire file structure to `.php`. Using JS is ok, but what will you do if the user disables JS? Then you're up `that creek`. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery and the `load()` function

Update you links with a class

```
<div id="menu_lat">
    <a class="loader" href="http://localhost:8080/sgf/form_proposta.php">Orçamentos</a>
    <a class="loader" href="relatorios.html">Relatórios</a>
    <a class="loader" href="proximos.html">Próximos Eventos</a>
    <a class="loader" href="chat.html">Chat</a>
</div>
```

Then in your `<script>` tags add this to handle the click event on your links with the class loader.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.loader').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // stop the link loading the URL in href
        $('#conteudo').load($(this).attr('href'));
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: I just add that to my script tags and I'm able to use jQuery in my page? I didn't study it yet, neither Ajax. :/

Comment: Link is loading the URL in the entire page

Comment: You will also need to include the jQuery library itself, see updated answer

Comment: Had to include jQuery locally, but now nothing is happening when I click the link.

Comment: Oops, I guess nothing was happening because the folder was outside htdocs. Now it's working perfectly. :D Many thanks, sir!

Answer (score 1):

DO the Ajax call on the DIV id conteudo